# Information not pushing to FireBase Realtime Database correctly

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a simple form requesting couple questions from the user. I am attempting to connect my FireBase account so the realtime database can get updated when the user presses the submit button. However, the database is not receiving any information. I have attached the code.

The problem is somewhere in the HTML or JavaScript. I have inserted random alerts to see if they would work, and I get them to come up. I removed some of the "dataLink.push" commands, due to my FireBase only containing 2 values (name, value). I am a beginner with FireBase.

```js
var config = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCdqgGdZH8bWSMiHEM7ZoeWSNfZ04uA3Y8",
    authDomain: "errandboi-f1cf5.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://errandboi-f1cf5.firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "errandboi-f1cf5.appspot.com",
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);
// Creates a variable called databaseLink that links to our database.
  var databaseLink = new Firebase('https://errandboi-f1cf5.firebaseio.com/');  
  // Create javascript variables that link our previous HTML IDs.  Remember, we can't use regular HTML inside a script tag, so we need to use JQuery to reference any previous HTML.  A $ means we are using JQuery
  var messageField = $('#task');
  var nameField = $('#name');
  var contactField = $('#contact');
  var locationField = $('#location');
  var miscField = $('#misc');
  var messageList = $('#example-messages'); // DELETE MAYBE?????
  //alert(messageField);
  // If the enter key is pressed, push the values in the text boxes to our database.
  function push(){
    alert("yo");
    messageField.keypress(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {                            //13 is the enter key's keycode
      alert("yo");
      if (messageField.val() == ""){                  //Ensure that an activity was entered.
        alert("Please let us know how we can help!");
      }else{
        //push data to firebase and then clear the text box
        databaseLink.push({name:nameField.val(), value:messageField.val()});
        messageField.val('');
      }
    }
  }
  });//end of keypress function
```

```html
<DOCTYPE! html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<!--THIS IS NEEDED TO IMPORT FIREBASE LIBRARIES -->
  <script src="https://cdn.firebase.com/js/client/2.2.1/firebase.js"></script>
<!-- THIS IS JUST A NICE LOOKING FONT -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans" rel="stylesheet">
<!--THIS IS NEEDED TO IMPORT JQUERY LIBRARIES -->  
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js'></script>
<!-- THIS IS TO IMPORT MY JS FILE -->
<script src="index.js"></script>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>ErrandBoi!</title>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
 <header>
  <h1 class="title">ErrandBoi</h1>
 </header>
 <div id="banner">
  <h2>Your Helping Hand in Every Situation</h2>
 </div>
 <div id="content">
  <p class="content">Ever have an emergency while you are in class? Life has got you all tied up but your tasks won't do themselves? Well, you are at the right place for help. Let ErrandBoi take the stress off your shoulders while you can do what really matters. Simply, fill out the form below with any* task that you may need help with and one of our drivers will help you out as soon as possible!</p>



 <br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>



 <div class="form-style-5">
<form method="POST">
<fieldset>
<legend><span class="number">1</span> Your Information</legend>
<input type="text" name="field1" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *">
<input type="email" name="field2" id="contact"placeholder="Contact Information (Email, Phone Number, etc.) *">

<input type="location" name="field2" id="location" placeholder="Your Location (i.e. McNutt, Hodge Hall, exact address, etc.)*">
<input type="text" name="field3" id="misc" placeholder="Miscellaneous Information That May Be Important"></textarea>
<label for="job">Urgency:</label>
<select id="job" name="field4">
<optgroup label="Urgency level: just for us to prioritize properly">
  <option value="Not Urgent">Low (ETA: Up to an hour)</option>
  <option value="reading">Normal (ETA: Up to 45 mins)</option>
  <option value="boxing">Critical (ETA: ASAP!)</option>
</optgroup>
</select>      
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
<legend><span class="number">2</span>Task that needs completion</legend>
<input type="text" name="field3" id="task" placeholder="Let Us Know How We Can Help!*"></input>
</fieldset>
<input type="submit" value="Apply" onClick = "push()"/>
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, did you solved this problem? :)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to mix Firebase v2 and Firebase v3. In order to make it work you should:

1) Import the right Firebase sdk (and remove the old one from your code)

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.1.0/firebase.js"></script>
```

2) Get a reference to the firebase database

```
var databaseLink = firebase.database().ref();
```

**NOTE:** Firebase has been updated recently, the new documentation is at [firebase.google.com](https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup) (not firebase.com)

Hope it helps ;)